# If you use the creation spell to create gunpowder/blackpowder, how long would it last?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

If you use the *creation* spell to create gunpowder/black powder (assuming you have seen it), how long would it last? What material/materials would it fall under?

Comment: i didnt know that! i will make sure too do that, i defiantly see what you mean

Comment: I would really not recommend to do that. Introducing real-world sciences like physics or chemistry to a DnD campaign is a good way to break it. The rules of DnD were not designed to be balanced against real-world technology. You will end up with players turning low-level utility spells like *create food and water* into weapons of mass destruction. When you want to have a character in the campaign who is able to brew exploding concoctions, then you might want to look for a supplement rulebook with rules for alchemy.

Comment: oh! i am a pc, the dm was curious how we could replicate gun powder!

Comment: Is "until it blows up" not the kind of answer you are looking for? 

Answer (score 11):

#### 12 hours

*[Creation](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Creation#content)* says:

> The Duration depends on the object's material. If the object is composed of multiple materials, use the shortest Duration.
>
> - Material - Duration:
> - Vegetable matter - 1 day
> - Stone/crystal - 12 hours
> - Precious metals - 1 hour
> - Gems - 10 minutes
> - Adamantine/Mithral - 1 minute

Gunpowder, or [black powder](https://www.nps.gov/casa/learn/historyculture/gunpowder.htm#:%7E:text=Black%20powder%20consists%20of%20a,in%20gunpowder%20provides%20the%20oxygen.),

> consists of a fuel (charcoal), an oxidizer (saltpeter or niter), and a stabilizer (sulfur) to allow for a constant reaction.

- Charcoal is vegetable matter (wood); 1 day
- Saltpeter, aka [potassium nitrate](https://www.thoughtco.com/saltpeter-or-potassium-nitrate-608490#:%7E:text=Saltpeter%20is%20a%20common%20food,medication%20for%20lowering%20blood%20pressure.) or nitre, is a mineral.  As neither a precious metal nor a gem, it would last 12 hours
- Sulfur is also a non-precious-metal, non-gem mineral; 12 hours

The shortest duration of these three is 12 hours, so by *Creation*'s description, their mixture would also last 12 hours

Comment: I wonder what category(ies) _smokeless_ powder would fall under...

Comment: @Vikki — none, it is an (al)chemical product and as something not fitting into these groups can't be created, just as you can't create meat and bone that way.

Comment: @Vikki-formerlySean is the *smokeless* powder Skoal, Copenhagen, or Happy Days Mint?